# Ajax autocomplete issues

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json

I'm having some issues with an asp.net implementation of this [JQuery facebook style autocomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html).

Basically the json url I am using is an aspx page that takes some paramaters via the query string and writes json to the response. This appears to be functioning correctly however the plugin doesnt recognise it.

The strange thing is when I take the Request.QueryString out of the page (still passing it the querystring) and hard code the values the autocomplete works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you log what query strings are passed to .aspx in the page itself? Create a file to log the whole url which is passed. I bet that there is an issue with passing the query string correctly, maybe they are not correctly encoded.

Comment: heres an example - json_url: "../Services/Job/UnassignedUsers.aspx?p=12&j=71"

Comment: Can you install mozilla add-in firebug and check in the console what URL is called? Do you have the site online?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah found the problem thanks to the tip from Pawel.

The autocomplete uses a query parameter to do the search resulting in something like - UnassignedUsers.aspx?p=12&j=72?tag=a